# Manually updating software installed with apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates

I have `libphp-phpmailer` which was installed with `apt-get`. This software has a version with security patches that is not in the version available through `apt-get` updating.

Is it safe for me to manually remove and replace the files for this software with the new version? If not, what additional steps need to be taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove with `apt-get`, then find deb package for version you are looking for and install using `dkpg -i <package-file>.deb`

If you get dependency errors, case gets more complicated. We will need more info to help.

Comment: Nope, I think that will work.